# Flection & flexion

Tags: etymology

As far as I know, " flection" and "flexion" are synonymous. I have two questions:

1- Are the two words of the same origin?

2- Which one is more modern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Oxford English Dictionary puts both spellings under the same heading, so yes, they are synonymous. Here's how the OED explains the two spellings:

> The etymological spelling flexion is the original in English; flection (first in 18th cent.) is due to the influence of such words as affection, direction, etc.

Additionally, "flexion" is a word in other languages while the more recent spelling "flection" is unique to English.

Comment: _Flexion_ is not a word in Latin, though it is the stem used for declining one: the nominative is _flexiō_ with no n.

Comment: You're completely right, I just edited my answer to fix the error.